# How to insert data into a sql data table via stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I want to insert data from a dataset in asp.net into a SQL Server table.

But I can't pass the values from dataset to my stored procedure plz help me

Here is my code

```
private static SqlCommand WriteDatabase(SqlConnection conn)
{
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SP_insertData);
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameterCollection pc = cmd.Parameters;

            pc.Add(CreateParameter("abID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
            pc.Add(CreateParameter("fHitType", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
            pc.Add(CreateParameter("DateOfHit", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime));
            pc.Add(CreateParameter("TimeOfHit", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
            pc.Add(CreateParameter("fEmpid", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return cmd;
}

private static SqlParameter CreateParameter(string p, SqlDbType sqlDbType)
{
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@" + p, sqlDbType);
        parameter.SourceColumn = p;
        return parameter;
}
```

I can't pass values from dataset to my stored procedure

Comment: Where is your DataSet in that code?

Comment: thats my problem
i don't know how to solve it

Comment: i try to create a windows service to read data from one database and insert it into an other database
at first i read data from DB1 and copy into a dataset then i copy my data into an other dataset
this steps are worked fine, but now i cant read data from The second   dataset and insert into my database

Comment: If you have more no of records in datatable then Convert datatable to xml string and pass it to DB. It will be quicker than loop. If you need the code then i can post that too.

Comment: Yes, Please write this code for me
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this code:

```
SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

  public Boolean InserData(string abID, string fHitType,string DateOfHit, string TimeOfHit,string fEmpid)
{
    // SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection("Connection_String");
    SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand();
    oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
    oCommand.CommandText = "SP_insertData";
    oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@abID", abID);
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fHitType", fHitType);
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfHit", DateOfHit);
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeOfHit", TimeOfHit);
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fEmpid", fEmpid);
    oConnection.Open();
    Boolean Result = Convert.ToBoolean(oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());
    oConnection.Close();
    return Result;
}
```

It will return true or false Returns true means your data has been saved successfully and return false means not saved...

Comment: i want to pass parameters from my dataset to my stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it

```
SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

public int InserData(string abID, string fHitType, string DateOfHit, string TimeOfHit, string fEmpid)
{            
    SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("SP_insertData", oConnection);           
    oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@abID", abID);
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fHitType", fHitType);
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfHit", DateOfHit);
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeOfHit", TimeOfHit);
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fEmpid", fEmpid);
    oConnection.Open();
    int Result = oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    oConnection.Close();
    return Result;
}
```

if Return Type 1 then suceess else not insert Successfully